# Flash banner ad syncing as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, banner

How do I ensure that 3 banners (2 skyscraper and 1 leader board) play at the same time when they appear on a webpage?
I need to send the files to a third party site that will host the banners.

Do I have to ad code to each banner file - or do the ad hosts do something their end?

I'm using as3 and any help appreciated in simple terms as i'm not a code wizard!
Many thanks.
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using ExternalInterface class in AS3 and JavaScript in ad page. So it needs some collaboration with the hoster.

Your banners need to have two functions:

```
function reportReady():void {
    // here you report ready by calling JS-side function via ExternalInterface
    // you also have to report banner ID,
    // so use banner1, banner2, etc. for different banners
    ExternalInterface.call("reportReady", "banner1"); 
}

function startAnimation():void {
    // here you start animation, and don't forget to stop calling reportReady()
}

// also you need to register a callback to hear calls from JS
ExternalInterface.addCallback("startAnimation", startAnimation);
```

Now have the reportReady function be continuously called with some intervals, say 1/10 s. But make sure it starts calling only after banner has finished loading. That's all you need in AS3.

Now, the JS part. In the page code, you need a JS function and a holder for three banners state:

```
var banner_list = [false, false, false];

function reportReady(banner_id) {
    // some very basic code to determine which banner called
    if (banner_id == "banner1") banner_list[0] = true;
    else if (banner_id == "banner2") banner_list[1] = true;
    else if (banner_id == "banner3") banner_list[2] = true;
    // now check if all three banners have reported, also very basic code
    if (banner_list[0] && banner_list[1] && banner_list[2]) {
        // activate all banners here using their ids
        document["banner1"].startAnimation();
        document["banner2"].startAnimation();
        document["banner3"].startAnimation();
    }
}
```

"banner1", "banner2" and "banner3" are id's of your Flash objects in HTML.

If you happen to have some problems, read about ExternalInterface, there's plenty info and examples on the web.